# I can't seem to select divs nested in divs (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm using the Brackets editor and I'm not sure if it's a problem with the editor or the live preview (localhost) or if I'm doing something wrong.

I can access individual ID's just fine but once I attempt accessing ID's inside of other ID's (which are also divs) it doesn't ...access them but I don't really get an error either. It just won't do anything.

For instance, I've tried both

```
#myId > #myId2 {}
#myId #myId2 {}
```

I've tried including the word 'div' as well but no luck...any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Without more information it'll be hard to determine.  Can you set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or try just running the file in the browser to narrow down the possibilities?

Comment: have you given width and height to ur divs?

Answer (score 0):

it should work if u doing it this way:

HTML:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

              <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
                <script src="script.js"></script>
              </head>

              <body>
                <div id="parent">

                  <div id="child" class="child">

                    <div id="grandChild" class="child">

                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>
              </body>

            </html>
```

CSS:

```
            #parent{
              height: 200px;
              width: 200px;
              background-color: red;
            }

            #grandChild{
              height: 50px;
              width: 50px;
              background-color: lightgreen;
              border-radius: 20%;
            }

            #parent>.child{
              height: 100px;
              width: 100px;
              background-color: lightblue;
              border-radius: 50%;
            }
```

In the demo below try to change #parent>.child to #parent .child and see the difference.
[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/EjMI1ZycvGuopD1RE4Oh?p=preview)

Perhaps u forgot to give a height and width to ur divs as i said above in comments?

hope that helps.